# Why is List<string> being saved in application settings but LinkedList<string> isn't?

Tags: c#, settings.settings

This is my Settings.setting file:

```
 <Setting Name="AutoCompleteList" Type="System.Collections.Generic.LinkedList&lt;string&gt;" Scope="User">
      <Value Profile="(Default)" />
 </Setting>
```

and this is my Settings.Designer.cs:

```
public global::System.Collections.Generic.LinkedList<string> AutoCompleteList {
   get {
       return ((global::System.Collections.Generic.LinkedList<string>)(this["AutoCompleteList"]));
   }
   set {
       this["AutoCompleteList"] = value;
   }
}
```

Programs.cs

```
class Program
{
    private static LinkedList<string> _autoCompleteList;
    static void Main()
    {
        _autoCompleteList = new LinkedList<string>((new[] {"one", "two"}));
        
        Settings.Default.AutoCompleteList = _autoCompleteList;
        Settings.Default.Save(); //Nothing is saved. (Silently and without any error)
        
        _autoCompleteList = Settings.Default.AutoCompleteList; //null
    }
}
```

If I use `List<string>` instead of `LinkedList<string>` all things work; but I need `LinkedList`, because it makes it easier to access the previous and next elements. Yes. It's possible using `List` in app settings and load it into a LinkedList at runtime, but I want to know why `LinkedList` can't be saved in app settings.

Also I should have made it clear that all my settings are scoped as "User"

Comment: Do you get an error message or does it just silently "do nothing"? If the former, please provide the error message, if the latter, please provide a [mcve], so that others can debug the issue.

Comment: Why are you using `LinkedList` in the first place?

Comment: Why do you *think* you want to store a linked list in your settings? It being a linked list is an *implementation detail of an in-memory representation* of a list.

Comment: @JonasH Because in my use case I need access pervious and next item easily.

Comment: A regular list can just as easily access next/previous item. Just take the index and add/subtract one. While linked-list is sometimes promoted in data science classes, it is rare that it has an advantages over a regular list in practice.

Comment: @JonasH I understand what you are saying, but working with `LinkedList` with syntactic sugar properties like `First`, `Last`, `Pervious`, `Next` and `Find` is less bothering than handling index in a List or an Array. Anyway, thank you for your suggestion

Comment: `Find`, `First`, `Last` are all provided for List already, either thru linq or build in. `MoveNext` is provided by calling `GetEnumerator`. It would be fairly trivial to create a iterator object with a `MovePrevious` method, using a `IReadOnlyList` as the backing interface.

Comment: I'm about to be convinced. 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linked list is a data structure that is implemented in memory only because each element also linked to another element. That's why it can't be saved. It just can be implemented in memory.